# launching app fails in instruments

Tags: ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I am using  OS 10.10.3 and tried to run instruments 6.1/6.2/6.3 and launch different debug apps.
All launched and crashed after 2 seconds.
I tried restarting my computer and the device and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting all versions of Xcode from my computer and another thing, if you are using Xcode-beta then you need to change the path from /Applications/Xcode.app to  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app
using sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app